# Utility to determine application (or process) that displayed a (hung) window?

Tags: windows, process, utility

Just curious if such a thing exists -

I have a hung window on my screen (you know, the kind that 'captures' images of the last window that you move over it), and I was wondering if anyone knows of a utility that will "work backwards" and help me determine what process/application on my PC created/owns the 'hung' window?

Obviously I appreciate that a restart of my PC would 'cure' this, but I don't want to have to go through that process, and I don't fancy playing roulette with running processes in task manager.

I've rummaged around the web and also searched the sysinternals website but nothing jumps out at me - I figured if someone knows, they're bound to be on here :-)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) from Microsoft sysinternals, it's free

Once launched, drag the target symbols from the menu bar upon your hanged windows. It will then highlight the process owning this window.

This is just a small hint, this tool is heavy can do a lot more..Learn it !

Answer (score 1):

I second using Procexp, it can be packed on a flash drive and is immensely useful, and can even be setup to replace task manager, and has saved me tons of work, though really everything Mark Russinovich makes is quite awesome.

Comment: Even better, you can run the tools right from the SystemInternals site. Both via SMB \\live.sysinternals.com or HTTP http://live.sysinternals.com